# Excluded from a research project

Tags: research-process

I am a new Ph.D. student. The professor has announced a new idea for a quick paper project and invited us to discuss about it. At the end of the discussion, he asked who's interested and I asked explicitly to join the project. I found out later that the professor is meeting with some of his students (excluding me) and they have done a progress. I asked him via email if I can join future discussion and if he can share the progress with me. He did share a documentation of the progress but he's still meeting with few of his students without me. What annoys me the most is that I am the only student who worked on related topics during my master's and still doing so. Involving me would have been very beneficial in every aspect.

I can't help it but taking it personally! Is this normal in research groups? What actions should I take now?

Comment: I vote to close. This is clearly an interpersonal conflict. I can't see what we can usefully provide as an answer other than "you need to have an in-person conversation with your boss about this".

Answer (score 6):

It is possible he thinks you have more important things to work on. There might be some positive reasons for his actions. It may even be that some of the other students need a boost by working on something "simple". Or, since you are new, that the others need something to fill out their CVs before graduation.

You might try asking him why he thinks this is more appropriate for others than for yourself.